# How to create this static route on macos?

Tags: macos, network

I am trying to set up an xdebug inside a docker such as it communicates with PhpStorm. I have found [steps for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263043/how-to-setup-docker-phpstorm-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04/46265103#46265103) which sounds promising. However, the following command fails to run on macOS (`sudo: ip: command not found`). I failed to translate the following Linux command to a macOS command.

```
sudo ip addr add 10.254.254.254/24 brd + dev wlp4s0 label wlp4s0:1
```

How to run it on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
sudo route -n add -net -ifscope wlp4s0 10.254.254.254/24 10.254.254.1
```

Source: `man route`